Looking for the equivalent Tcl_FileObjCmd function in tcl 8.6.6
I am trying to move to tcl 8.6 from tcl 8.4. In my project there was an use of function **Tcl_FileObjCmd **however this function is not available tcl 8.6.6. I am not able to find its equivalent to implement the functionality.
Please help to find the same. Documentation/ChangeLog etc. does not help much.
I searched for it in the documentation but could not find it. I could find a new function Tcl_InitFileCmd in tcl 8.6.6 but need an example to use it in place of Tcl_FileObjCmd. Interface is also different here. Also I am not sure how to pass the arguments provided by the user to this new function as earlier function was having.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

There is nothing like Tcl_FileObjCmd() itself any more; that function was removed in 8.5. It was the implementation of the file command, and command implementations were never supposed to have been part of the public C API. It won't be coming back either; file is now an ensemble with a totally different implementation strategy. (The subcommands are now themselves Tcl commands.)
If you are wanting it to call operations, either use the real API for doing those operations — most have counterparts with reasonably obvious names — or invoke the command (probably via Tcl_EvalObjv() as that avoids going through the interpreter). There are a few things where that is the right approach, mostly because we never expect them to be used directly from C.

Thanks @Donal Fellows. Could you please share an example of ensemble if I want to use that.

They're documented with examples. Tcl's internal ensembles always use the -map option as that's resolved enough for the bytecode compiler to work with, but you don't need to do that when making your own.
